# android - Get facebook page post without user login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, restfb

I'm trying to create an android app that shows the facebook public page post. I tried to use facebook android sdk and it seems that the app needs to be review but my app does'nt need to login the user, I want only use my own access token. So I try to use restfb but I'm facing problem when I use it. So my question is:

Without user login and using only my access token. What is the best method to use when getting the facebook public page post? android sdk or restfb.
***note: I do not own the page***

Comment: You can try getting the HTML through simple GET request and parse the page using a HTML parser library like jsoup

Comment: What if Facebook change some of their codes like changing the style, changing the structure?

Comment: That's a risk. But if you try to get the posts by using css selectors, I don't think it should be a problem because facebook doesn't change that structure a lot.

Comment: I consider jsoup as my last option but as much as possible i want to use api or like using json

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. don´t do that. only use the api. if there is no way with the api, it´s most likely not allowed. use an app access token - you will have to go through a review process though. facebook does not want you to just grad stuff from pages you don´t own without them reviewing your usage.

Comment: But it says there that I need a screencast that shows how the user login to the facebook. In my app I don't have the feature of using Facebook login. Is it okay to ignore that?